# how to use Alamofire with custom headers

Tags: swift, afnetworking, alamofire

I am just starting to take a look at Mattt's wonderful new Alamofire swift networking library and am not quite sure how one would use it with custom headers.

The code i am trying to convert from AFNetworking to Alamofire is this:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.setValue(authorizationToken, forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization")
```

Comment: `defaultHeaders` is a mutable dictionary (`[String: String]`) of headers. I think you should be able to add your headers to that.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

According to the official documentation, modifying the session configuration is not recommended:

> This is not recommended for Authorization or Content-Type headers.
>   Instead, use URLRequestConvertible and ParameterEncoding,
>   respectively.

So an example usage of URLRequestConvertible for authorization would be:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseUrlString = "some url string"

    case Get(query: String)

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        let (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) = {
            switch self {
            case .Get(let query):
                return ("/get", ["q": query])
            }
        }()

        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseUrlString)!
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        // set header fields
        URLRequest.setValue("a", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL        
        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    }
}
```

and when you want to make a request:

```
Manager.sharedInstance.request(Router.Get(query: "test"))
```

More info about URLRequestConvertible: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#urlrequestconvertible

### Old Answer

As of Alamofire v1.0 Pers answer no longer works. In the new version additional headers should be added to the `HTTPAdditionalHeaders` property of `NSURLSessionConfiguration`

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": authorizationToken]
```

More info here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/111

Comment: This is working also for iOS 7? Apparently, for me is not working on iOS 7, only on iOS 8.

Comment: @MihaiPanţiru it worked fine on iOS 7 when I tested it. It is possible that the latest changes to Swift broke something. I'm in a bit of a time crunch so I'm unable to verify.

Comment: wrapping this in an enum seems peculiar to me - can you explain your rationale for that please? EDIT: Ah nevermind, I get it :)

Comment: @NikolaLajic can you specify which version of Alamofire you are referring to ?

Answer (score 43):

For headers that change from request to request, you can pass them directly to the request method. From [the docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#http-headers):

> Adding a custom HTTP header to a Request is supported directly in the global request method. This makes it easy to attach HTTP headers to a Request that can be constantly changing.

And the example given:

```
    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", headers: headers)
             .responseJSON { response in
                 debugPrint(response)
             }
```

If, however, you wish to set headers that do not change, it is recommended that you do so on the NSURLConfiguration object, as others have mentioned here.

Answer (score 38):

At this time , Swift 3.0 , Xcode 8.x, Alamofire 4.x:

You can use custom header as below:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/headers", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

For [reference](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-headers)

Comment: in this where your passing parameters?

Answer (score 15):

I've created a static headers method in a separate APIManager class.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class APIManager {

    class func headers() -> HTTPHeaders {
        var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]

        if let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "auth_token") {
            headers["Authorization"] = "Token" + " " + authToken
        }

        return headers
    }
}
```

And I use it in requests:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString,
                      method: .get,
                      headers:APIManager.headers())
```

Comment: Perfect code :)

Answer (score 8):

For Alamofire 5:

```
let path = BaseServiceApi().baseUrl + "login"

let params = [
    "phone": "+9232222222",
    "password" : "123123123"
    ] as [String : Any]

let request = AF.request(path, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: APIManager.headers(), interceptor: nil)

request.responseDecodable(of: UserModel?.self) {(resposnse) in
    
    let user = resposnse.value
    print(user)
}
```

APIManger Class for headers:

```
class APIManager
{
    class func headers() -> HTTPHeaders
    {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
        
        return headers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE**: this was before 1.0. **It no longer works**, look at the accepted answer instead.

---

You use the defaultHeaders property on the Manager singleton to add headers, like this:

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.defaultHeaders.updateValue(authorizationToken, forKey: "Authorization")
```

At least it works for me. :)

Answer (score 5):

Because I dislike setting these things globally (and sometimes I send them, sometimes I don't), I wrote a wrapper method to set the headers with each call.

```
import Alamofire

public class Service: NSObject {

    private class func request(method: Alamofire.Method, URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String : AnyObject]?, encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL, headers: [String: String]? = nil) -> Request {

        let (request, error) = encoding.encode(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLString.URLString)!), parameters: parameters)
        let mutableURLRequest = request as! NSMutableURLRequest

        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

        if let heads = headers {
            for (field, value) in heads {
                mutableURLRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: field)
            }
        }

        return Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
    }
}
```

It can be called as follows...

```
Service.request(.POST, URLString: "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: ["example-param": "example-param-value"], encoding: .JSON, headers: ["example-header-field": "example-value"])/*.whatever you want to do with it*/
```

It could certainly be cleaned up with some error checking, but this should give you the gist of it. It's all based on Alamofire 1.2.

Answer (score 5):

**Alamofire 4.x, XCode 9.1, Swift 4.x**

When Headers cause problem while sending it in the request, then we need to encode parameter, for this we do **JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted** or **JSONEncoding.default** like :

```
let url = "http:\your.url.string\"
let parameter = ["Username":"name", "Password":"123"]
let headers = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]

Alamofire.request(url, method : .post, parameters : parameter, encoding : JSONEncoding.default , headers : headers).responseData { dataResponse in

     print(dataResponse.request as Any) // your request 
     print(dataResponse.response as Any) // your response
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting below code will only works in iOS 8 and above.

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = headers
```

Below is the full code which works for iOS 7 and iOS 8

```
let URL = NSURL(string: request.url!)
var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.GET.rawValue

// Adding headers
var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

// Adding parameters
let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
let urlReq  = ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: request.params).0
aReq = manager.request(urlReq)
aReq!.responseJSON { (req, response, JSON, error) in }
```

More info : [GitHub - Alamofire Issues](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/111)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an `NSMutableURLRequest` object directly to Alamofire, since it has an extension for `NSMutableURLRequest` that adopts `URLRequestConvertible`.  So there's no need to create your own class to just add an Authorization header.  It's as simple as this:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.setValue(authorizationToken, forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization")

Alamofire.request(request)
    .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, error) in }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   let aManager = Manager.sharedInstance
    aManager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Some authentication Token here" ]


    let URL =  "some url string"

    request(.GET, URL, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON {
            (request, response, data, error) -> Void in

            if(error != nil)
            {
                if let delegate = self.delegate {
                    delegate.connectionDidFinishedErrorResponceForAction!(1, andWithResponse: nil)
                }
                println("\(error!.localizedDescription)")

            }
            else {

                if let delegate = self.delegate {
                    delegate.connectionDidFinishedForAction!(1, andWithResponse: nil)
                }
               println("req:\(request) \n res:\(response) \n json:\(data!) \n \(error) ")
            }
    }
```