# Use Alamofire with WatchKit?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Is there any best-practice how to use Alamofire with Watchkit to make simple HTTP requests?

I am using the latest Xcode 6.3 beta

Comment: If you want to make simple HTTP requests NSURLConnection or NSURLSession are more than enough. They're lightweight and simple. Also, I'd like to refer you to this answer which suggests that you shouldn't perform any HTTP requests in a WatchKit extension, let alone complex and long running ones: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28931587/832065

Comment: Don't use Alamofire? Is it really that difficult to use NSURLSession.....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking an example- weather app in watchkit practice - as follows:

**Part 1:**

- http://connectthink.com/developers-corner/creating-a-watchkit-app-using-swift-part-one/

**Part 2:**

- http://connectthink.com/developers-corner/creating-a-watchkit-app-using-swift-part-two/

Here are some links that I consider it might be useful for you or for others.

`Alamofire` GitHub website:

- https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

There are a lot of useful materials for `Alamofire` in the following links

- http://nshipster.com/alamofire/
- http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/7/30/parsing-json-in-swift
- http://iheartswiftlanguage.com/

Apart from them, the following great explanation could be useful

- [how to use Alamofire with custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143938/how-to-use-alamofire-with-custom-headers/26055667#26055667)